# Azure Data Factory Pricing - Activity Count

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm thinking of using Data Factory in order to copy data from a Blob Storage container to an SQL table but I'm not quite sure I understand how the pricing works, specifically how the activities are counted.

So if I have a pipeline with 3 activities that copies the data from a CSV with 1000 lines will the total activity count be 3*1 or 3*1000? In other words, will I be charged based on the number o files it processes or the total number of lines it copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's 3 activity runs. Activity runs are measured by the thousand, at $1 per. Since these are Copy activities, they consume Data Integration Units (DIU) at $.25 per hour. Pipeline execution time is billed at $.005 per hour. If you add all this up for 1 pipeline with 3 Copy activities that runs for 1 hour, your total bill is like 27 cents.

We run THOUSANDS of pipelines a month, all with many activities including quite a few Copy activities. Our Data Factory billing is still so low that it looks like a rounding error in our total Azure spend.

The exception to this is Data Flow. Data Flow is a Spark wrapper, so you have to pay for Cluster time, which can get expensive quickly if you aren't careful.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have a pipeline that executes some other "child" pipelines. Each of these take < 1 minute to run at a cost of 4 DIUs per hour. The Azure portal seems to calculate each of at 0.0067 DIU-hour. So, it's rounding to the nearest minute I guess. Do you know if I will be charged as if i'd used the full minute on each of these runs? Or in reality if the run only takes 20seconds, will it be one third of this amount?

Comment: I don't know if they bill by the minute or the second, and I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Comment: I found out that it does charge by the minute, and it rounds UP. So my 20second process is being charged for the whole minute. But the bigger part of the cost comes from it rounding up the activities, the pipeline duration cost is negligible, as you say

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to pay for 2 important metrics: Orchestration and Execution. Please refer to more details from this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/).

1.Orchestration, $1 per 1,000 runs. You have 3 activities, then it should be $ 3/1000.

[image]

2.Execution, it depends on the DIU you configured,which means the performance of your transmission.

[image]